# Code First Migration A network-related

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-migrations

I'm working with `MVC` project (Code first) I did some changes on the Model then I did Migration, but errors occur:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to `SQL Server`. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

My Connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CodingContext" connectionString="Data Source=Hp-Hp;Initial Catalog=CodingDatabase;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I tried my project in other PC but the same errors appear. Could anyone help me to solve this error and explain why this error appears?

Comment: This your first migration? You were able to `enable-migrations` and `add-migration`? You are doing these from the console (not in code)? You have the project with the migrations selected in the console? You could try supplying parameters to the [ef commands](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/).

Comment: Yes, It is the first migration from my PC and I did it from the console. Migration from my laptop works fine.Migrations have already been enabled in my project.